# Getting error in retrieving type from an array contained in a list of object using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Optional<List<Spot>> geoData = getGeoCodeBat(geocodeRequestDTO, reportResponseDTO); //declaration of geoData
//**geoData is a list of object**
// **getting syntax error in map**
// **Errors is an array inside geocodes**
geoData.get().stream().map(m -> { 
    Arrays.stream(m.getErrors()).forEach(i ->{
        if(i.getType()==1) //Type is an field inside the Errors array
          {
            reportResponseDTO.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); //setting bad request in response
             reportResponseDTO.setStatusCode(400); // setting the bad request value
          }
    });
```

Comment: do update the question with minimal entities and the error message.. and stop using `Optional<List<>>`, a list can be empty to represent the absence of elements

Comment: It's a syntax error that I get in the map @Naman

Comment: What is the type of `m.getErrors()`?

Comment: @Naman there are some cases when `Optional<List<>>` does make sense. Thus `Optional.empty()` can mean `no list at all` which is logically different from `empty list`.

Comment: errors is an array inside geoData. m which is an object of geoData gives errors array using m.Errorrs() @Naman

Comment: @ETO IMHO, such data type should not be represented as a `List<T>` but `R` instead. It's better to wrap the datatype within another user-defined one.

Comment: @bubka85 As I had asked previously as well, without the actual classes and input-output, the question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question correctly. But you could try this:

```
boolean isBadRequest = geoData.orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
                              .stream()
                              .map(Spot::getErrors)
                              .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                              .anyMatch(i -> i.getType() == 1);

if (isBadRequest) {
    reportResponseDTO.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    reportResponseDTO.setStatusCode(400);
}
```

Comment: I solved it by using peek instead of map. But thanks a lot @ETO

Comment: @bubka85 Do not use `peek`. Its execution is not guaranteed.